# SQL Server VARBINARY INSERT Locks Table for 30+ Minutes

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a simple table I create and populate:

```
USE MyDB
GO

CREATE TABLE dbo.mytable (
    my_id INTEGER IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    description VARCHAR(MAX) NOT NULL,
    image VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO dbo.mytable (
    description, image
)
SELECT
    'foo',
    CAST('bar' AS VARBINARY(MAX));
```

The query finishes successfully. Then I try:

```
SELECT * -- Or SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM MyDB.dbo.mytable;
```

And wait forever...

Running the query found [here](http://sqlblog.foxraven.com/2012/01/check-to-see-if-table-is-locked.html) I see 5 exclusive locks (3 X, 2 IX) that aren't released for ~30 minutes. Once the locks are released SELECT queries finish almost instantly.

Why are these locks kept for so long?
What can I do to reduce the time between INSERT and SELECT?

*Note that the INSERT in the above example was used as a manual test after attempting to insert an image from one of my applications exhibited the same behavior. The image used is ~14.2kB in size.

Comment: Try adding `COMMIT;`, probably open transaction. Also you could consider to set [RCSI](https://sqlperformance.com/2014/05/t-sql-queries/read-committed-snapshot-isolation) mode.

Comment: Are transactions implicit? Or rather, are they lazily committed? All other queries seem to commit immediately.

Comment: Every insert is executed within the scope of a transaction. This is part of the ACID principal. That means that an insert that does not have an explicit transaction will run under an implicit transaction. They are not lazily committed. They are either committed or rolled back immediately.

Comment: @SeanLange Interesting - I wasn't aware of that. I'm still confused however. That would mean the insert itself (or rollback) is responsible for keeping the locks around. I don't see why an insert as simple as this would take so long (over an hour at this point).

Comment: >>>Running the query found here I see 5 exclusive locks (3 X, 2 IX) that aren't released for ~30 minutes.<<<< And what spid was holding these locks?

Comment: @sepupic Thanks for asking that question - it inspired me to look and I discovered that the spid related to my application (running on a Pi). Somehow the connection wasn't closed after the app exited. Restarting the PI released the locks.

Comment: @lad2025 Adding `COMMIT;` solved the lock issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you have open transaction (probably implicit). I suggest to add `COMMIT` after `INSERT`:

```
INSERT INTO dbo.mytable (description, image)
SELECT 'foo',
        CAST('bar' AS VARBINARY(MAX));

COMMIT;
```